# Change Text Node Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, dom

I am working with an XML file in MatLab and I want to change the Text value of a node.

Say I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetBeam>
 <ControlPoints>
  <Cp>
   <Mu>2</Mu>
   <GantryRtn>40</GantryRtn>
  </Cp>
 </ControlPoints>
</SetBeam>
```

What I want to do is change the value `2` of the `<Mu>` node to `4`.

I tried doing this:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Mu').item(0).childNodes(0).nodeValue = '4'
```

...but it did not work.

Is there a different command than `nodeValue` that I have to use in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way without using external libraries. `setTextContent` does work.

```
xmlDoc = xmlread('sample.xml');

xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Mu').item(0).setTextContent('4');

% Create a new xml file and for checking that Mu value has changed
xmlwrite('new.xml', xmlDoc)
```

I've tested in R2018b.

Comment: Thank you! This works fine if I hardcode the `'4'` into the `setTextContent` attribute. However, if I have calculated 
`value =4` beforehand and saved it with `diff = sprintf('%.1f', value)` in the `diff` variable, it gives me an error: `Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.` if I put `.setTextContent(diff)`. How can I make this work?

Comment: In MATLAB R2018b, the following also works without an error.

   `value = 4;
    diff = sprintf('%.1f', value);
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Mu').item(0).setTextContent(diff);
    xmlwrite('new2.xml', xmlDoc)`

Which version are you using?